# Filtering the state data doesn't work fine - React (CRA)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, react-state, react-state-management

I have created a simple todo application. I can add items to the todo, and filter the list through `all`, `completed` and `incomplete`. All the lists are rendered respectively. The problem is when I am any of the `completed` or `incomplete` filters, and I check or uncheck the task respectively, the list should be filtered again on each check/uncheck. I am able to call the `filter` method, but having some unexpected behavior of the state, it removes the list elements except that I check/uncheck when any of the filters are active.

I have created this sandbox, play around it.

[Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-http-3igof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you check an item, in `modifyList` you are setting `copiedList` to the previous state of `list`, which is a filtered subset of the entire data.
changing `setList` to `setCopiedList` seems to have solved the issue for me.

```
const modifyList = (list) => {
  setCopiedList((prevState) => {
    let state = [...prevState];
    return state;
  });
};
```